# WiX not writing registry values (Win 7 x64)

Tags: windows-7, wix, registry

I am new to WiX and I have become completely stumped as to how to create registry keys during the installation process. I am using the `RegistryKey` and `RegistryValue` elements like this:

```
<Component Id="RegKeys" Guid="824A9E7D-211C-4404-80F7-6AC4185B1E66">
    <RegistryKey Action="createAndRemoveOnUninstall" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\My\Path">
        <RegistryValue Name="MyKey" Type="string" Value="Blah blah blah"/> 
    </RegistryKey>
</Component>
```

with a corresponding call to `ComponentRef` for the main feature:

```
<ComponentRef Id="RegKeys"/>
```

The installer builds fine and runs without any apparent errors but no keys or values are created under the `Wow6432Node` key (or anywhere else for that matter). The installer is for a 32-bit application but I am trying to install it on Windows 7 64-bit.

What am I missing (I'm sure it's something obvious)? We are using WiX 3.5.

Comment: Does the registry path you put into @Key attribute exist?

Comment: @Yan, yes, the path exists. Could I not use RegistryKey to create it though even if it didn't? Or does that need to be performed as a separate step?

Comment: I expect it to fail silently if there's no path in registry to inject new key to... however, I didn't try it myself, I might be mistaken.  Try to author a simple WiX project with only 1 component with that registry key to narrow down the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things to try:

1. Use Orca from the Windows SDK to verify the value is present in the Registry table. (This eliminates a build problem.)
2. Check a verbose log to see what MSI is doing with the component and what it does with the registry data.

Comment: I ran Orca and I can see two related entries in the Registry table. Both have SOFTWARE\My\Path as their Key but one is named MyKey (expected) and the other * (not sure what this is). 'MyKey' has a value of #%blah blah blah; * doesn't have a value at all. I also ran a verbose log - there is nothing in there relating to the keys/values I am trying to set (although there is one attempt to write to the registry with a blank key and blank value). Not sure if it's related or not.

Comment: You don't need Action="createAndRemoveOnUninstall". See http://www.joyofsetup.com/2010/05/14/working-hard-or-hardly-working/. A value of #%whatever indicates that your authoring specifies Type="expandable" or your value includes a percent sign. If you're trying to write an environment variable, use [%VARIABLE]. See "Formatted" in the MSI SDK for details.

Comment: I finally found the culprit: `<Property Id='REINSTALLMODE' Value='as'/>` was preventing registry entries from being written (although I'm not sure why). Your mention of Orca pointed me in the right direction because when I performed a validation it reported an ICE40 warning, 'REINSTALLMODE may cause problems'. I guess it was right! :)

Answer (score 1):

Is the registry value alone in its component? If so, set KeyPath to "yes".

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, Cosmin. I tried adding KeyPath="yes" but it didn't make any difference, unfortunately.